# 'Attention: This is not the latest available version' Error on TestLink

Tags: testlink

I'm getting 'Attention: This is not the latest available version' on the test execution page of TestLink.

The test case is not versioned. Is this error for something else.
The TestLink version is the latest available.

Did anyone face same kind of issue earlier?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I traced everything down from gui to database and yes, I finaly found the solution!
We both are using an old view, no idea how we got there.
Maybe we missed an update over time...

Please use the following mysql code to update your view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW /*prefix*/latest_tcase_version_id
AS SELECT
   LTCVN.testcase_id AS testcase_id,
   LTCVN.version AS version,
   TCV.id AS tcversion_id
FROM /*prefix*/latest_tcase_version_number LTCVN 
join /*prefix*/nodes_hierarchy NHTCV 
on NHTCV.parent_id = LTCVN.testcase_id 
join /*prefix*/tcversions TCV 
on TCV.id = NHTCV.id 
and TCV.version = LTCVN.version;
```